# Shutdown/Restart takes forever after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, shutdown, 22.04

So I recently upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04, but now my computer takes minutes to shut down or restart. It just shows a black screen with the following messages: Running guests on default URI:
libvirt-guests.sh [9545]: no running guests.

This seems to only occur when I restart after logging in and only if I login to Gnome, not KDE Plasma, though I'm not entirely sure about that.

The only solution I tried was disabling the service libvirt-guests with this command: "systemctl disable libvirt-guests", which leads to just a black screen without any messages, but doesn't solve the problem.

Anyone got a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem occured on my computer for a few days,maybe open the kvm mode because before downloading the docker-desktop,I turned the CPU kvm-mode on,you can turn off it and restart again.

Comment: Same problem. I upgraded 20.04 to 22.04.1 yesterday. `sudo init 0` and `poweroff` can't shutdown my computer, the screen is off, but the power light is on and cpu fans still run. It could only be shutdowned by force power-off.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I upgraded my Kubuntu OS to use Ubuntu 22.04. At the shutdown, I observed a never-ending black screen without the machine being powered off.

Here's what worked in my case:

I used the following command to observe the last shutdown logs.

```
journalctl -rb -1
```

Many log entries were from the *chrome-remote-desktop* application and service daemon failing certain operations. Therefore I removed the Chrome remote desktop from Chrome browser and also from the OS system with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove chrome-remote-desktop
```